# Ending stanza in Birkat HaMazon

Tags: sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, moshe-rabbeinu, bentching, meal-seudah

In some Sephardic/Edut HaMizrach siddurim, there is a sentence as one concludes that one reads "ברוך הזן, ברוך שולחן, ברוך משה בן עמרם". [Hebrew Wikipedia](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%96%D7%95%D7%9F) records it as the custom of the Kurdistan community in Israel but gives no reference. Couldn't find the source for this custom. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the fact that Moshe wrote the first bracha in Birkat HaMazon.

Comment: @ezra Moshe _enacted_ it משה תקן. He didn't necessarily write the text we have. Indeed many Nuschaot use a verse from a Psalm of David in the first blessing, which, on face value, Moshe didn't know about.

Comment: It is poetic! Perhaps there's no other reason?